# Use of If/else statement in Inlined XML Entry in WSO2 ESB

Tags: if-statement, xslt, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using Local Entry Inlined XML Entry in  WSO2 to perform some transformations. I have to check that if an element to hard-code to response values to my client response. For example, if they send 09 as response code, I have to send 00 after transforming.

```
<xsl:element name="ns1:ResponseCode">
     <xsl:value-of select="//jsonObject/d/SuccessCode"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: You can take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_choose.asp
If you have tried something that doesn't work - show us your code. Also, you might want to read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i have no idea how to do it but here my existing code <xsl:element name="ns1:ResponseCode">
                  <xsl:value-of select="//jsonObject/d/SuccessCode"/>
               </xsl:element>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `<xsl:choose></xsl:choose>` element.
It can contain as many `<xsl:when test="..."></xsl:when>` elements as you need, and one `<xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>` element.

In the case you described:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com">
<xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SuccessCode">
    <xsl:element name="ns1:ResponseCode">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//jsonObject/d/SuccessCode/text()='09'">
                <xsl:value-of select="'00'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise/>  
        </xsl:choose>               
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this is an example and you should add the other transformations and update the namespace.

Comment: Thanks men.its Work but not in Choose its IF.any way thanks i got logic from you. <xsl:if test="//jsonObject/d/SuccessCode/text()='1'">
                  <xsl:element name="ns1:ResponseCode">
                     <xsl:value-of select="'00'"/>
                  </xsl:element>
               </xsl:if>

Comment: hey if you have any idea how to give else part of this
<xsl:if test="//jsonObject/d/SuccessCode/text()='1'">
                  <xsl:element name="ns1:ResponseCode">
                     <xsl:value-of select="'00'"/>
                  </xsl:element>
               </xsl:if>

Comment: If you want to achieve "if-else" like structure, you can use "choose - when/otherwise" - it does exactly what you want to do. "when" is where the condition is - you can have multiple conditions, i.e. multiple "when"s in the same "choose" element. "Otherwise" is like "else". The other option, if you want to use "if", is to use a second "if" with the opposite condition. @Kasun